# difference between canvas and gl.canvas

Tags: javascript, opengl, canvas, opengl-es, webgl

in WebGL, we create a rendering context with

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("#mycanvas");
let gl = canvas.getContext("webgl2");
```

in every operation I see people using gl.canvas just instead of canvas, I wish to know why,

like to find aspect ratio,

```
let aspectRatio = gl.canvas.clientWidth/gl.canvas.clientHeight;
```

why don't we use canvas element instead of gl.canvas .

Comment: Have you read the [relevant documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/canvas)? You don’t need `const canvas` if you can use `gl.canvas`.

Comment: yes, I have read the docs but couldn't understand, does this mean there where I see gl.canvas, I can use canvas only?

Comment: Both refer to the same `HTMLCanvasElement`, there's no difference, most of the time it's just convenient to use the `canvas` member of the context object so one doesn't need to pass both, canvas and context.

Comment: @LJᛃ thank you this is what I wasn't sure of !!! I thought there might be a reason to pass in some cases of which I am not aware. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.